# OpenCV concave and convex corner points of polygons

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-2.7, contour

### Problem

I am working on a project where I need to get the bounding boxes of dumbell like shapes. However, I need the fewest points possible, and the boxes need to fit the shapes at all corners. Here's an Image I made to test: [Blurry, cracked, dumbell shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP9vc.png)

I don't care about the gaps going into the shape, I just want to clean it up, and straighten the edges so that I can get the contours of a shape like this: [Cleaned up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EqKS.png)

I have been attempting to `threshold()` it out, getting the contours of it using `findContours()` and then using `approxPolyDP()` to simplify the crazy amount of points the contours end up being. So, after fiddling with this for about three days now, how can I simply get either:

- Two boxes specifying the ends of the dumbell and a rectangle in the middle, or
- One contour with the twelve points for all the corners

The second option would be preferred since that really is my ultimate goal: getting the points that are at those corners.

### A few things to note:

- I am using OpenCV for Python
- There will generally be many of these shapes of all sizes all over the input image
- They will have only horizontal or vertical positioning. No strange 27 degree angles...

### What I need:

I really don't need someone to write the code for me, I just need some method or algorithm in order to get this done, preferably with some simple examples.

### My Code

Here is my overly clean code with functions I don't even use but figure I would use them eventually:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

class traceImage():

    def __init__(self, imageLocation):
        self.threshNum = 127
        self.im = cv2.imread(imageLocation)
        self.imOrig = self.im
        self.imGray = cv2.cvtColor(self.im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        self.ret, self.imThresh = cv2.threshold(self.imGray, self.threshNum, 255, 0)
        self.contours, self.hierarchy = cv2.findContours(self.imThresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    def createGray(self):
        self.imGray = cv2.cvtColor(self.im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    def adjustThresh(self, threshNum):
        self.ret, self.imThresh = cv2.threshold(self.imGray, threshNum, 255, 0)

    def getContours(self):
        self.contours, self.hierarchy = cv2.findContours(self.imThresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    def approximatePoly(self, percent):
        i=0
        for shape in self.contours:
            shape = cv2.approxPolyDP(shape, percent*cv2.arcLength(shape, True), True)
            self.contours[i] = shape
            i+=1

    def drawContours(self, blobWidth, color=(255,255,255)):
        cv2.drawContours(self.im, self.contours, -1, color, blobWidth)

    def newWindow(self, name):
        cv2.namedWindow(name)

    def showImage(self, window):
        cv2.imshow(window, self.im)

    def display(self):
        while True:
            cv2.waitKey()

    def displayUntil(self, key):
        while True:
            pressed = cv2.waitKey()
            if pressed == key:
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    blobWidth = 30
    ti = traceImage("dumbell.png")
    ti.approximatePoly(0.01)
    for thresh in range(127,256):
        ti.adjustThresh(thresh)
        ti.getContours()
        ti.drawContours(blobWidth)
    ti.showImage("Image")
    ti.displayUntil(10)
    ti.createGray()
    ti.adjustThresh(127)
    ti.getContours()
    ti.approximatePoly(0.0099)
    ti.drawContours(2, (0,255,0))
    ti.showImage("Image")
    ti.display()
```

### Code Explanation

I know I might not be doing some things right here, but hey, I'm proud of it :)

So, the idea is that there are very often holes and gaps in these dumbells and so I figured that if I iterated through all the threshold values from 127 to 255 and drew the contours onto the image with large enough thickness, the thickness of drawing the contours would fill in any small enough holes, and I could use the new, blobby image to get the edges and then scale the sides back down to size. That was my thinking. There's got to be another, beter way though...

### Summary

I want to end up with 12 points; one for each corner of the shape.

### EDIT:

After trying out some erosion and dilation, it seems that the best option would be to slice the contours at certain points and then use bounding boxes around the sliced shapes to get the right boxy corners, and then doing some calculations to rejoin the boxes into one shape. A rather interesting challenge...

### EDIT 2:

I discovered something that works well! I made my own line detection system, that only detects horizontal or vertical lines, and then on a detected line/contour edge, the program draws a black line that extends across the whole image, thus effectively slicing the image at the straight lines of the contours. Once it does that, it gets new contours of the sliced up boxes, draws bounding boxes around the pieces and then uses dilation to close the gaps. So far, it works well on large shapes, but when the shapes are small, it tends to lose a bit of the shape.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You've done a good job of defining your problem, but the code you posted contains a lot of elements unrelated to your actual problem. It's hard to see what you're actually doing through all the declarations. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which will allow people to help you more quickly.

Comment: "There will generally be many of these shapes of all sizes all over the input image"
If the shapes do not intersect, extract them and process them one by one. 

"They will have only horizontal or vertical positioning. No strange 27 degree angles..."
If your contours are only horizontal or vertical, just extract the contours, eliminate tilted contours then elongate the remaining contours a little to close potential gaps.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Aurelius! I really appreciate it! I will definitely try to update my code with more concise declarations.

Comment: @a.lasram That's not a bad idea, but sometimes the contours consist of hundreds of points and in order to know the angle of contours, wouldn't you need two points to get the angle? I'm a little wary of iterating through many points considering the image could be gigantic. But after thinking about your method, it seems like it might work. Gives me some things to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after fiddling with erosion, dilation, closing, opening, and looking at straight contours, I have figured out a solution that works. Thank you @Ante and @a.alsram! Your two ideas combined helped me get to my solution. So here's how it works.

### Method

The program iterates over each contour, and over every pair of points in the contour, looking for point pairs that lie on the same axis and calculating the distance between them. If the distance is greater than an adjustable threshold, the program decides that those points are considered an edge on the shape. Then the program uses that edge, and draws a black line along the whole contour, thus cutting the contour at that edge. Then the program redetermines contours and since the shape was cut. These pieces that were cut off are know their own contours, which then are bounded by bounding boxes. and finally, all shapes are dilated and eroded (close) to rejoin the boxes that were cut off.

This method can be done several times, but each time there is a little bit of accuracy loss. But it works for what I need and certainly was a fun challenge!  Thanks for your help guys!

natebot13

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Maybe simple solution can help. If there is a threshold length to close a gaps,
it is possible to split image in a grid with cell lengths >= threshold, and use
cells that have something inside. With that there will be only horizontal and
vertical lines, and by taking a care about grid to follow original horizontal
and vertical lines it will cover main line features.</strike>

**Update**

Take a look on [mathematical morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology). I think closing operation with structuring element (2*k+1)x(2*k+1) pixels can do what you are looking for.

Algorithm should take threshold parameter k, and performs dilation and than erosion. That means change image so that for each white pixel set all neighbours on distance k ((2*k+1)x(2*k+1) box) to the white, and than change image so that for each black pixel set  neighbours on distance k to the black.

It is enough to do operations on boundary pixels.

Comment: I will definitely look into that and try it! Thanks. Now to attempt to wrap my head around all the equations and symbols... Lots to learn!

Comment: Alright, so after some tests and experiments using dilation and erosion, the final image looks like [this.](http://i.imgur.com/PrcuATR.png) It's almost there... But not quite.

Comment: There are round corners. You are using circle for a neighbouring region, instead use square with length 2k+1. Lower right 'hole' is because of parameter k, try to increase it.

Comment: I am using a square struct element, with (2k+1), however the round corners still exist. Also, the "hole" in the lower right corner could be fixed, only if the struct element were really big, while in the final program, the struct element must remain small. In fact, it must be the smallest, (3,3). However, I have figured out how to get this accomplished very nicely, and I will post an answer to my own question.